# drop down select with jQuery autofill > upon select .show(); div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery autofill setup, from a drop-down `<select>` tag. It's working great however, I have one problem; I am trying to simple `.show();` a specific div when the user selects one of the '`autofill`' suggestions; *ie.* from one of my drop-downs. All my efforts thus far have been failing, I have been inspecting the selectors outputted in dev console and adding a click function in JS to `.show();` my div, however nothing is being read, and I'm imagining it's due to a `z-index` issue or something about how the jquery is rendering the `select > ul > li` elements for the autofill. In any case any suggestions on how I might be able to achieve this?

[image]

*ie.* Above is a screenshot, once, say 'Colorado' is selected, or 'clicked' `.show();` div.

My attempts look something like `(with attempted use of various selectors)`

```
$('input').click(function(event) {
     $(".state_overlay").show();  
    // $('li.ui-menu-item').innerhtml().append.$("h2.statename"); /* edit */
});
```

My jquery base autofill code...

```
$.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      if(this.element.is("select")) {
        var self = this;
        this.original = this.element.hide();
        this.element = $("<input/>").insertAfter(this.original);
        this.options.source = function(request, response) {
          var filter = $.ui.autocomplete.filter,
            $options = self.original.find("option"),
            result = $options.map(function() {
              return $(this).html();
            });
          response(filter(result, request.term));
        };
      }
      this._super("_create");
    },
    _destroy: function() {
      this._super("_destroy");
      this.element.remove();
      this.original.show();
    }
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete();
  });
```

My mark-up looks like this:

```
<select id="autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [**`autocomplete`**](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) builtin events like `select`

```js
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: ["NY", "", "NJ", "CT", "PA", "NC", "VA"],
  select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui);
    var selectedItem = ui.item;
    //your logic goes here
    if (selectedItem.value == 'some value')
      $('some div').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input id="autocomplete">
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/51/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete1" /> 
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
Your Content
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
var countries = [      
  "Albama",
  "Colorado"      
];

$(document).on('click','.ui-autocomplete li div',function(){
    if ($(this).text() == "Colorado")   
  {
  $("#div1").show();
  }
});


$('#autocomplete1').autocomplete({
            source: countries,
            minLength: 0,
            scroll: true
});   


});
```